# MAC Slider custom implementation with own images

Tags: macos, slider

Can any one tell me how to implement custom slider in mac objective C with my own images?( Not for Iphone)

Answer (score 0):

You need to override and do your own drawing in [`NSSliderCell`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSliderCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

I linked the documentation up there for you and believe the place for you to start is with the `drawKnob` method.

[Here is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985816/custom-nsslidercell) (with sample code!) that may help you out.